# Using MySQL db functions (?) with SQLite (Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite

I'm using a [tutorial](https://webdeasy.de/en/complete-login-system-with-node-js-vue-js-restapi-jwt-part-1-2/#register) to do JWT/bcryptjs auth and then `INSERT` into a SQlite
table.
Thing is the tutorial is for MySQL and I get errors like `db.query is not a function`
and `db.escape is not a function`

The db :

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()

const DBSOURCE = "./src/db/db.sqlite"

let db = new sqlite3.Database(DBSOURCE, (err) => {
if (err) {
  // Cannot open database
  console.error(err.message)
  throw err
}else{
    console.log('Connected to the SQLite database.')
}
});

module.exports = db
```

Example query :

```
db.query(
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(${db.escape(
  req.body.username
)});`,
(err, result) => {
  if (result.length) {
    return res.status(409).send({
      msg: 'This username is already in use!'
    });
  } else { .........
```

My best guess is that the functions are different?

How do I get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of proprietary functions in MySQL that will not work with standard SQL in other database systems.

That is just the beginning of the [differences between Mysql and SQLite](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-whats-the-difference/#:%7E:text=SQLite%20is%20a%20server%2Dless,to%20interact%20over%20a%20network.)

Provide some query examples and we may be able to assist you with each one.

-- update after your addition of query code...

Here is an example of [sqlite-nodejs](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/)

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

// open the database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/chinook.db');

let sql = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(?)`;

db.all(sql, [req.body.username], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    rows.forEach((row) => {
        console.log(row.name);
    });
});

// close the database connection
db.close();
```

Comment: Thank u. I edited the post with an example query. How would u do it with SQLite?

Comment: sqlite-nodejs https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/

Comment: did not run code with updated prepared statement, but it should be close to right. :)

Comment: db.run example with unescaped string ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30080602/372215